# Interrupting custom transition in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipresentationcontroller, custom-transition

While trying to implement custom transition animation, I stucked in interruption part. The thing I want to do is, by tapping `dimmingView` during transition, it should be cancelled and presented view controller dismised.

This is my dimming view:

```swift
class UIDimmingView: UIView {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        return hitView == self ? nil : hitView
    }
}
```

This is how I create and assign tap gesture recognizer to my dimming view:

```swift
lazy var dimmingView: UIDimmingView = {
    let view = UIDimmingView()

    view.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    view.alpha = 0.0

    return view
}()
```

```swift
override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
    guard let containerView, let presentedView else { return }

    containerView.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
    containerView.insertSubview(self.dimmingView, at: 0)

    self.dimmingView.fillSuperview()

    presentedView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    presentedView.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
    presentedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

And simply, `onTap` event, I do this:

```swift
@objc private func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

The final result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skwT4.png).

I looked on Google, asked ChatGPT. However couldn't find a way to dismiss it in the middle of transitioning. How can I do it?

Comment: You probably want to look into `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`

Comment: @DonMag , I thought the same and tried to present it interactively. However, it broke the animation(instead of sliding from bottom to top, it appeared immediately). After that, I couldn't go further. Have you had a similar experience?

Comment: Kind of tough to say at this point, because you haven't shown what your "custom transition" is doing... A standard transition runs for 0.3 seconds (I believe) - have you written a transition that animates for several seconds, where it would make sense to be interruptible? Searching for `swift custom interactive transition` comes up with lots of articles / tutorials / examples / etc. If you can't find any tips there, maybe edit your question and describe better what you're trying to do. It's possible there is a better solution than a custom transition to begin with.

Comment: FYI - you should avoid using the `UI` prefix for your own classes. It's reserved for UIKit. You run the risk of a naming collision as well as causing confusion for other readers of your code.

Comment: @HangarRash thank you for your kind feedback. You're right. I haven't considered such a collision can occur with UIKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through the internet, I found the cause of my issue. It was basically due to a non-interactive presentation style. If you want your "dimmingView" to respond to user interactions and be interruptable from the beginning, you should present your view controller interactively by providing the proper interactor class via:

```swift
func interactionControllerForPresentation(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning?
```

Previously, I only made the dismissal interactive. So, it didn't get the gesture calls during the presentation.